# Google VR Video View in Android Freezes

Tags: android, video, view, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I wonder if this happened to anyone else so far. I am developing an app that is sending Bluetooth strings to Arduino while playing VR video. I am using Note 4 for testing and Android Studio for development.

The video and bluetooth works just fine until i put in the 4k video. It starts playing it and if not in "cardboard mode" it works. But as soon as we go to "cardboard mode", the video freezes. The voice continues to play in the background and if i go out of "cardboard mode" it continues the playback.

Any ideas to why this is happening? I have implemented VR video View just as Google suggests (from their test code). Monitor shows no errors, nothing. When i check the GPU monitor i just some really bad spikes when entering "cardboard mode", but then it just stops.

Comment: please edit your post and include your so we can help you faster, thanks